# SQL query updating twice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update column and increase it's value by 1.

I tried this code on my local server but actually it's increasing by 2 and I don't know why (I found out this when i check the column value later).

```
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "root");
define("PASSWORD", "root");
define("DB", "dbname");
$con = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB);

if ($con->connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  exit();
}

$query = "UPDATE `active_games` SET current_question = current_question + 1 WHERE pin_code = " . $pin_code;
  if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
    echo "Update successfully! <br />";
  }
  else {
    echo "There was an error.. <br />";
  }

$con->close();
```

Comment: There's nothing in your PHP that would update the table twice. Perhaps you have a trigger causing the update, or your PHP code is being called twice?

Comment: What exactly is `current_question` and are you sure, that you don't call your code twice? Do you have a `db` class and a function to handle your `question`s logic?

Comment: where is $pin_code called? Share some detailed code. The code you share has nothing that could reload the page or called twice the update query.

Comment: That’s all the code. 
I’m using phpmydmin and over there I see the column updated twice.

Comment: Did you test it in multiple Browsers? Maybe the reason y is the preload "feature" of chrome browser? [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9116376?hl=en-GB)

Comment: @Fabricio You were right! On Firefox it's not happening! only by using Chrome. What should i do to prevent it on chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the Chrome preload feature. You can try change the page to accept POST not GET, and change links to reflect it.

As POST request assumes that you are sending something important chrome doesn't use preload feature. At least, it didn't do it when i got this problem before.

Try change your code to this.

```
define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "root");
define("PASSWORD", "root");
define("DB", "dbname");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') && (isset($_POST['DOIT'])) {
    $con = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DB);

    if ($con->connect_errno) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
      exit();
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `active_games` SET current_question = current_question + 1 WHERE pin_code = " . $pin_code;
      if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
        echo "Update successfully! <br />";
      }
      else {
        echo "There was an error.. <br />";
      }

    $con->close();
}else{
    echo '
    <form action="?" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="DOIT" value=1>
        <input type="submit" value="Update Current Question">
    </form>';
}
```

I just added an if to validate the POST request.

Comment: Actually right now it's not received any POST or GET request. The purpose of the page is just to update the database (I ran into this problem with a bigger project and this 
page is just to figure out the problem)/

Comment: @MaorBenezri If you load the page using Chrome by typing the url and hitting enter, Chrome send a GET request to your page. Unfortunately Chrome doesn't send anything to differ a preload from a loading.